# Graphical archive manager that uses /tmp

Tags: archive, tmpfs

I am looking for a (preferably) graphical archive manager that can be configured to use `/tmp` as a scratch area for decompressing.

My setup is as follows: I have my local workstation with `/home` mounted from a NFS partition which works well in general and I also have a good chunk of RAM so I have `/tmp` setup as a RAM disk. I also need to work with large (100-300MB) `tar.*` and `zip` archives on a regular basis. In my testing, I've found that decompressing to `/tmp` and then moving the files into the NFS mount is orders of magnitude faster, however doing this currently requires me to drop out to a shell and do it all manually so I rarely bother unless I need something done quickly.

So, does anyone have any thoughts on applications that I could use to hopefully automate this a little more? I could easily write a console level wrapper to do the job, but I'm hoping for something that I can use from/with nautilus.

Comment: The problem with that might be the sticky bit set on directory permissions in the /tmp dir.  You might need to unstick the bit after/during copying the file to your current directory?  Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537437/can-tmp-in-linux-ever-fill-up

Comment: @djangofan: Why would the sticky bit be a problem? Wouldn't that be necessary for multiple people to use this sort of thing effectively? I'd expect any well-behaved application that does what I've described above to clean up behind itself, but you're right it's something to watch out for (especially with a ramdisk)

Comment: I use a patched file-roller to do that

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Xarchiver](http://xarchiver.sourceforge.net/).  See also this blog post:  [How to Install Xarchiver (archive manager) in Ubuntu Linux?](http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-install-xarchiver-archive.html)

You can choose the temp dir under Action -> Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Try [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/). It's a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystem that lets you access archives transparently. Run this command once and for all:

```
mkdir -p ~/.avfs
grep -q "^avfsd $HOME/.avfs " /proc/mounts ||
avfsd ~/.avfs -o auto_cache
```

AVFS exposes the content of an archive `/path/to/foo.zip` as a directory `~/.avfs/path/to/foo.zip#` (same path, but under the AVFS mount point, and with an extra `#` at the end). This extra directory doesn't appear in the listing of `~/.avfs/path/to`, you have to navigate to it explicitly.

With the `auto_cache` option, the AVFS daemon keeps a cache in memory (and perhaps also in `/tmp`? I don't understand AVFS's cache policy.). Experimentally, with the `auto_cache` option, AVFS opens the archive every time you access a file in it, but only reads a few bytes from the file, not the whole file.

[Gvfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS), the virtual filesystem layer of Gnome, provides more transparent access to archives. I don't know whether it can be coaxed into caching archive contents.